# Android Studio - Google Vision for android 6

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-studio-2.3, google-vision

I want add flashlight control to my code on android studio (for android 6).
I'm using google vision and thi is my actually code:

Android Manifest:

```html
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT"/>
        
        <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
        <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash" />
```

Gradle:

```
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:11.0.4'
```

XML file:

```html
    <SurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/surface_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:foregroundGravity="center" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/barcode_value"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="No Barcode"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="119dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="474dp" />
```

Activity:

> public class Qr3 extends AppCompatActivity{
>
> ```
>         private BarcodeDetector barcodeDetector;
>         private CameraSource cameraSource;
>         private SurfaceView cameraView;
>         private TextView barcodeValue;
>         private boolean flashavAilable = false;
>         private boolean hasFlash;
>         private boolean isFlashOn;
>
>         #Override
>         protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>             super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>       setContentView(R.layout.activity_qr3);
>       //start verify flashLight
>             hasFlash = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH);
>             if (!hasFlash) {
>     //alert "noflash exist"
>     else{
>       //alert "flash exist"
>             flashavAilable = true;
>
>     }//end verify flashLight
>
> int permission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
>                 Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
>         if (permission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {makeRequest();}
>
>             cameraView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surface_view);
>             barcodeValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.barcode_value);
>
>             barcodeDetector = new BarcodeDetector.Builder(this)
>                     .setBarcodeFormats(Barcode.ALL_FORMATS)
>                     .build();
>             cameraSource = new CameraSource.Builder(this, barcodeDetector)
>                     .setAutoFocusEnabled(true)
>                     .setRequestedFps(60.0f)
>                     .setFacing(CameraSource.CAMERA_FACING_BACK)
>                     .build();
>             cameraView.getHolder().addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
>                 @Override
>                 public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
>                     try {
>                         cameraSource.start(cameraView.getHolder());
>                     } catch (IOException ex) {
>                         ex.printStackTrace();
>                     }
>                 }
>                 #Override
>                 public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {}
>                 #Override
>                 public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {cameraSource.stop();}});
>     #Override
>                 public void receiveDetections(Detector.Detections<Barcode> detections) {
>                     final SparseArray<Barcode> barcodes = detections.getDetectedItems();
>                     if (barcodes.size() != 0) {
>                         barcodeValue.post(new Runnable() {
>                             #Override
>                             public void run() {
>                                 //Update barcode value to TextView
>                                 barcodeValue.setText(barcodes.valueAt(0).displayValue);
>                                 cameraSource.stop();
>                                 AlertDialog.Builder dlgAlert = new  
>   AlertDialog.Builder(Qr3.this);
>   dlgAlert.setMessage(barcodes.valueAt(0).displayValue);
>  dlgAlert.setTitle("Value:");
> ```
>
> dlgAlert.setPositiveButton("Again", newDialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
>                                           Override
>                                           public void onClick(DialogInterface >dialog, int which) {
>                                               try {
>                                                   //noinspection MissingPermission
>                                                   cameraSource.start(cameraView.getHolder());
>                                               } catch (IOException ex) {
>                                                   ex.printStackTrace();
>                                               }
>                                           }
>                                       });
>                                       dlgAlert.setNegativeButton("End", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
>                                           #Override
>                                           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {finish();}
>                                       });
>                                       dlgAlert.setCancelable(true);
>                                       dlgAlert.create().show();
>                                   }
>                               });
>                           }
>                       }
>                   });
>           }//end onCreate
>               //ascolta click pulsanti del volume per accendere o spegnere flash
>               #Override
>               public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
>                   int action = event.getAction();
>                   int keyCode = event.getKeyCode();
>                   switch (keyCode) {
>                       case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP:
>                           if (flashavAilable ) {
>                               if (action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
>                                   turnOnFlash();
>                               }
>                           }
>                           return true;
>                       case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN:
>                           if (flashavAilable ) {
>                               if (action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
>                                   turnOffFlash();
>                               }
>                           }
>                           return true;
>                       default:
>                           //riabilita fullscreen
>                           return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
>                   }
>               }
>           private void turnOnFlash() {
>                   if (!isFlashOn) {
>                       //turn on flashlight <-------------------------------------HELP
>                       isFlashOn = true;
>                       cameraSource.stop();
>                   }
>               }
>               private void turnOffFlash() {
>                   if (isFlashOn) {
>                       //turn off flashlight <-------------------------------------HELP
>                       isFlashOn = false;
>                   }
>               }
>           }

How may I control the flashLight?

(can anyone fix the formatting of the code in my question?)

Thanks